# Overriding TinyMCE's Default Formatting

Tags: tinymce

How can I override TinyMCE's default formatting for basic stuff like bold, underline, and strikethrough?  Currently the generated HTML uses styled spans, which is normally fine.  Unfortunately, in this situation I need to do some simple parsing and need the elements to be the old-style <b>, <u>, and <strike>.

The following code is what I currently have that doesn't work.  Applying these styles to content continues to wrap the content in styled spans.

```
$('<textarea></textarea>').tinymce(
{
    theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough",
    theme_advanced_buttons2: "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3: "",
    formats:
    {
        bold: { inline : 'b' },
        underline : { inline : 'u' },
        strikethrough : { inline : 'strike' }
    },
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer on the [TinyMCE forum](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=23121):

```
$('<textarea></textarea>').tinymce(
{
    plugins : 'legacyoutput', // this overrides the formats automatically
    // ...
} );
```